# ODE Theory: Are centers and linear centers the same for reversible systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

everyone!

I'm trying to prove that a linear center of a planar system IS a center when the system is reversible (invariant under the change of variables $t\mapsto -t$ and $y \mapsto -y$).  I fooled around with the setup for quite a while and came to the somewhat dubious conclusion that this may not be true unless the rest point lies on the $x$-axis.  Is that true?  Or should it be true regardless of the rest point's location (taking into account, of course, the mirror equilibrium)?

Thanks in advance if you can provide any assistance!

Comment: Reference to a proof is given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/615743

Answer (score 0):

I think it is implicitly assumed that the center in question lies on $y=0$. The notion of reversibility you stated appears to treat $y$ as the velocity function (this is why its sign is reversed when the direction of time is reversed). If this is indeed the nature of the system ($\dot x=y$), then equilibria can occur only when $y=0$.

Otherwise, one has a counterexample in the form of  two spirals: stable and unstable, symmetric about the $x$-axis, both linearize to a center.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly the conclusion to which I eventually came.